# Jooq and Spring boot: Upgraded JOOQ via starter: failed to bind spring.jooq.sql-dialect' to org.jooq.SQLDialect

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

So i upgraded spring-boot-parent-starter to 2.2.8.RELEASE, which results in jooq 3.12.4 . Previously i had 3.11.5.

I am getting the following error

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.jooq.sql-dialect' to org.jooq.SQLDialect:

Property: spring.jooq.sqldialect
Value: MYSQL_5_7
Origin: "spring.jooq.SQLDialect" from property source "applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/application.yaml]"
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.jooq.SQLDialect
```

Here is what my application.yaml was before

```
spring:
  jooq:
    sql-dialect: mysql_5_7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the whole error message you will see this:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.jooq.sql-dialect' to org.jooq.SQLDialect:

    Property: spring.jooq.sql-dialect
    Value: MYSQL_5_7
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:2:25
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.jooq.SQLDialect

Action:

Update your application's configuration. The following values are valid:

    CUBRID
    DEFAULT
    DERBY
    FIREBIRD
    H2
    HSQLDB
    MARIADB
    MYSQL
    POSTGRES
    SQL99
    SQLITE
```

MYSQL_5_7 is not a value supported by jOOQ open source. It's only availble in the pro version

```
MYSQL_5_7
@Pro
public static final SQLDialect MYSQL_5_7
The MySQL 5.7 dialect.
This dialect is available in commercial jOOQ distributions, only.
```

Comment: Ah, thank you I somehow missed that. So you cannot specify 5_7 anymore? What does it use then? Looking at the docs seems to imply you can use mysql_5_7 https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html

Comment: I updated my answer. MYSQL_5_7 is only available in the PRO version of jOOQ

Comment: What version did they remove support for 5_7?

Comment: According to the Issue it must have been 3.12.0 https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8551

Comment: Btw. why don't you upgrade to the latest Spring Boot version?

Comment: I am only upgrading spring-boot-starter to increase versions of some libraries we have that have security issues. I am just not increasing to the absolute newest version to avoid some breaking changes